# How to create dynamic source model in Magento 2 depend on database?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form, dynamic, source-model

Suppose MyEnity has column "status" in the database it values is 0,1,2

```
0 => None
1 => 'Good'
2 => 'Bad'
```

I want In **Add** Page, source model display

```
1 => 'Good'
2 => 'Bad'
```

In **Edit** Page, If "status" already is 0
it will display

```
0 => 'None'
1 => 'Good'
2 => 'Bad'
```

In **Edit** if it's status != 0
it will display

```
1 => 'Good'
2 => 'Bad'
```

Comment: Please add more information

Comment: For someone who wants to know my solution. I use this `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` to check the URL where my source model will be called. I think It is quite silly. \n
So I have to extend `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select` UI component - just simply add new attribute in node field `component='My_Module\path\to\js'`. I modify method `setInitialValue()` check this.value() to change variable `this.indexedOptions=indexOptions(myedit)`